# Finding in std::list

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, c++11, stl

Tell me please how to do that the best using STL.

I have class that has a member `std::list<SomeObject*>`. It's private member. I have only `const_iterator` to begin and end.

I'd like to check if list has some value. I need to check several values. I have access to members of SomeObject.
How to do it the best?

I'd like to use `std::find` or `std::any_of` or sth like that. But I don't want to define several predicate functions. 
List has pointers so I can't define `operator==`.

I can use C++11.

Comment: you can specify a lamdba when needed

Comment: If you don't want to define predicate functions (or lambdas) then you're out of luck.

Comment: Lambda - i think it's a good idea. I haven't know that. Thanks ratchet freak.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be a bit more specific. One way would be to use a function that you pass to the find function and that contains the policy for a successful return. Something like:

```
//You could also use a public member function of the Test class that provides the policy
bool my_find_function( const Test* item ) 
{
   return item->id == 10;
}
list<Test*>::const_iterator found = find_if( list.begin(), list.end(), my_find_function);
```

But honestly, the web is full of examples for the STL containers and I am pretty sure, there are a bunch of results for it here on Stackoverflow. Check the search function on the top right of this very page.

Comment: Do you think this looks good? 15 functions like: my_find_function1, my_find_function2, my_find_function3, my_find_function4 .... ? I think it's not a good idea. But maybe you're right. Thanks for your reply. I can solve this primitive problem I can use google. I asked advanced programmers to tell me how to do that the best, the nicest.

Comment: @pawell55555: If you need 15 functions then you're code design is probably not good in the first place. There are tons of possible ways to implement a fitting function (you could use a virtual member function of your test item as I commented...but without knowing the real code it's all presumptious. You know your code, get the grasp of it yourself. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to give a predicate to std::find and call operator== on the dereferenced objects, you can use an iterator adapter which automatically dereferences the pointer. Boost has an implementation for such an iterator, but it is straightforward to write your own and having one is handy.

```
#include <boost/iterator/indirect_iterator.hpp>

bool finder(std::list<SomeObject*>::const_iterator fist, 
            std::list<SomeObject*>::const_iterator last, 
            SomeObject const& x) 
{
   return std::find(boost::make_indirect_iterator(first),
                    boost::make_indirect_iterator(last),
                    x) != last; 
}
```

But this only makes sense when you want to use operator==. If you have different predicates, either define them as functions or define them locally as lambda functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It looks great but I have a problem. I've defined operator==
    bool operator==(const SomeObject& x, const SomeObject& y)
    {
        return x.id < y.id; // example
    }
I have several errors like: error C2784: 'bool std::operator ==(const _Ty &,const std::complex<_Other> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::complex<_Other> &' from const SomeObject ... and other errors. :(

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: Looks like you are comparing something to a std::complex object?

Comment: No, I have several errors.. It looks like compiler cannot find operator==. The last error is: error C2676: binary '==' : 'SomeObject' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator.... But if I try to compare two object of type SomeObject by typing: x == y. There are no errors. I don't know what is going on. :(

Comment: comparision operator matches to one of the templatized version of comparision operator in std namespace. Define your operator == inside std namespace { } to remove the error.

Comment: You shall defined new things in namespace std. Never. The only exception is to specialize templates in namespace std, e.g. specialize std::swap. @pawell55555: Can you provide a small example with generates the error when compiling?